# Hide player controls while fullscreen in YouTube

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to prevent YouTube's (HTML5) fullscreen player controls from showing whenever it first goes into fullscreen mode?

Like, don't show this automatically (at all):

[image: Youtube Controls]

I want it to still show if I move the mouse, as it does now.

I couldn't find anything in `about:config` on Firefox about this, only settings to disable the fullscreen button and the warning:

> This page is now in fullscreen.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to make it not pop up the controls at all, and i'm talking about the youtube controls yes.

Comment: @DavidPostill I would, but i can't find anything that even mentions the video controls, the search term is also quite broad and i can't seem to shorten it with some keywords... thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You can either disable it for good or leave it enabled. You can't have both states in full-screen at once. Controls can be controlled in `<iframe>` by:

- **controls=0** - player controls do not display in the player
- **controls=1** (default) - player controls display in the player

see: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Hyde** extension for Google Chrome ([link to Hyde](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hyde-%E2%80%94-hide-the-youtube-v/pmkpddhfbiojipiehnejbjkgdgdpkdpb)).

The introduction is as follows:

> When you pause a YouTube video, the player controls don't disappear. That makes it really hard to take a clean screenshot of the video. The controls also block your view, which can get really annoying. Hyde is a simple Chrome extension that allows you to hide or show the video player controls easily.